# Angular 13 Docker how to use brotli on nginx docker server?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, brotli

My point is to enable Brotli compression on my docker angular app.

Brotli is enabled in Angular build

package.json

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
            "options": {
              "customWebpackConfig": {
                "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
```

webpack.config.js

```
var BrotliPlugin = require('brotli-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new BrotliPlugin({
            asset: '[path].br',
            threshold: 0,
            minRatio: 0.8,
        })
    ]
}
```

Here's my docker file

```
# Use official node image as the base image
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine as build
    
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
    
# Add the source code to app
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/
    
# Install all the dependencies
RUN npm install
    
# Generate the build of the application
RUN npm run build --prod
    
#RUN apk add --no-cache nginx-plus-module-brotli
    
# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server
    
# Use official nginx image as the base image
#FROM macbre/nginx-brotli:1.19.10
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk --no-cache add brotli 
RUN apk --no-cache add nginx-mod-http-brotli 
#nginx-plus-module-brotli
    
# Copy the build output to replace the default nginx contents.
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/mindmarket-front /usr/share/nginx/html
   
# Expose port 80 443
EXPOSE 80 443
```

Here's my nginx config

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so; # for compressing responses on-the-fly
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80; #ipv6
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
        #rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent; we just replace request to https
}


server {
     # quic and http/3
    #listen 443 http3 reuseport;

    # http/2 and http/1.1

    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; #ipv6

    server_name  example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    brotli on;
    brotli_comp_level 6;
    brotli_types text/xml image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf image/vnd.microsoft.icon application/x-font-opentype application/json font/eot application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/javascript font/otf application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript  application/x-javascript text/plain application/x-font-truetype application/xml+rss image/x-icon font/opentype text/css image/x-win-bitmap;
   
    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

  # 0-RTT QUIC connection resumption
    #ssl_early_data on;
  # Add Alt-Svc header to negotiate HTTP/3.
    #add_header alt-svc 'h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400';

    # Sent when QUIC was used
    #add_header QUIC-Status $quic;


    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

docker run command

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name test -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem  -v /home/admin/nginx-default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro -d test:latest;
```

when i run the docker container I got this error

```
2022/02/18 12:42:52 [emerg] 1#1: "load_module" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:4
nginx: [emerg] "load_module" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:4
```

According to nginx documentation the load_module directive seems to be in the right place.
If I remove load_module nginx says it doesn't know brotli directive.
How could I fix this ?